# OpenCV How to run two videos at same speed?

Tags: opencv, video

how to make two video run at same time and same fps ?

```
VideoCapture capture("../video/Success/NT 1.1.wmv");

VideoCapture capture2("../video/Success/NT 1.wmv");

capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS , 30);

capture2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS , 60);

waitKey(30);
```

For example, i have this two video and i set the fps for these two videos already but this capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS , 30) doesn't work for my program..

Comment: setting the playback rate does not make any sense at all, as you have to grab frames sequentially from videocapture (and use your own timing).

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV is not a playback library, nor it was ever intended to support such functions. Setting FPS does absolutely nothing there.

The only thing that OpenCV does it to offer you the possibility to extract frames from a video, one after another.

You'll have to devise your own, complete, timing sequences to control the speed at which images are displayed on screen.

Or, better, use VLC.

Comment: Both of these two videos have different functions (e.g. background subtraction , and so on) to achieve my systems detection's objectives. So, these two videos have to run at same time and work the progress with each other. Video 1 could run with normal speed but video 2 run slowly than video 1 by 5 sec. Do you have any idea to solve this problems ?

Answer (score 0):

what is problem in writing very simple code for same fps:

```
// Open videos
VideoCapture capture("../video/Success/NT 1.1.wmv");
VideoCapture capture2("../video/Success/NT 1.wmv");
Mat frame, frame2;
while(..)
{
    capture >> frame;
    capture2 >> frame2;
    //imSHOW or do anything with these frame..
waitKey(30);
}
//Close video
```

Am I missing something or you?